# How do I bind the parameter 'this' to each element of an array when using forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, this, bind

**Language**: Javascript
**Operating System**: Ubuntu 14.04
**Browser**: Tested in Chromium, Chrome, Firefox.

**Background**

I'm making a HTML5 Canvas game that has various collectable items. The superclass for these items is `Collectable`, which has a `render()` function:

```
Collectable.prototype.render = function(){
    // renders the collectables
}
```

There are different subclasses of `Collectable`, all of which delegate `render()` to the superclass. For example:

```
var Heart = function(x, y) {
    Collectable.call(this, x, y);
}
Heart.prototype = Object.create(Collectable.prototype);
```

I instantiate my collectables by first creating an array containing all of my collectables:

```
var collectables = [];
var numOfEach = 5;
// IIFE so as to not pollute global scope
(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfEach; i++) {
        // TODO: make this cleaner
        var heart = new Heart(100, 200);
        collectables.push(heart);
        var gemBlue = new GemBlue(100, 200);
        collectables.push(gemBlue);
        var gemOrange = new GemOrange(100, 200);
        collectables.push(gemOrange);
    }
})();
```

Then in my game loop file, I have a `renderEntities()` function that repeatedly calls individual render methods on my objects:

```
function renderEntities() {
    // render my other objects
    ...

    // render collectables
    collectables.forEach(function() {
        // test what 'this' is bound to
        console.log(this);

        // call render method
        this.render();
    });
}
```

...however in this case `this` is bound to `window` and therefore `this.render` is not a function.

**Question**

How do I bind `this` to each individual element of my `collectables` array?

**My research**

I've read the [documentation for the `bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), but I'm afraid I can't work out how this would be applied with `forEach()` and my anonymous function.

I then found [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733758/passing-scope-to-foreach) which explained how `forEach` takes an optional parameter to set `this`. After reading the [documentation on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Using_thisArg) I tried the following with unsuccessful results:

```
 collectables.forEach(function() {
     // test what 'this' is bound to
     console.log(this);

     // call render method
     this.render();
 }, this);
```

...which obviously had the same effect of setting `this` to the global object.

```
 collectables.forEach(function() {
     // test what 'this' is bound to
     console.log(this);

     // call render method
     this.render();
 }, collectables);
```

...this got me a little closer, as `this` is bound to the collectables array as a whole, but obviously `this.render` is still not a function. I can't see what argument I can use here in `forEach` to bind `this` to each element of the array.

I have a feeling that after typing all this out the answer will be very simple. I'm relatively new to the concept of `this` so go easy on me!

I haven't found another question that answers this for me, or at least one that I'm able to understand given my level of knowledge. For example, I have considered the following questions:

- [Calling a class function in forEach: how Javascript handles “this” keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079213/calling-a-class-function-in-foreach-how-javascript-handles-this-keyword/28079250#28079250)
- [The invocation context (this) of the forEach function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707969/the-invocation-context-this-of-the-foreach-function-call)
- [Passing scope to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733758/passing-scope-to-foreach)

Comment: try `collectables.forEach.call(collectables, callback)`

Comment: Are you interested in using the `this` keyword specifically? It seems like your example would work if you included the array item as part of the `forEach` callback. E.g., `collectibles.forEach(function(collectible) { collectible.render(); });`

Comment: Also, wouldn't each object passed to the `forEach` callback have access to the `render` method? In that case you don't even really need `this` in the callback.

Comment: You can pass the this value to `forEach()` as a second parameter after the callback. `myArray.forEach((e,i,a) => this.render(e), this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.forEach()` facility passes three arguments to your callback function:

1. The current element of the array;
2. The index into the array;
3. The array itself.

Thus:

```
collectibles.forEach(function(collectible) {
  // the parameter "collectible" will be the
  // current array element
});
```

There's really no need to bind `this`, but if you absolutely wanted to you could:

```
collectibles.forEach(function callback(collectible) {
  if (this !== collectible)
    callback.call(collectible, collectible);
  else {
    // body of function
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, embarrassingly simple. I'd been so focused on `this` that I'd overlooked how `forEach` works.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to get the object associated with each collectable item. In this case, simply pass an argument for the `forEach` loop. In this case, I've called that argument `theObj` but perhaps `theCollectable` or even just `c` would be more accurate.

```
collectables.forEach(function(theObj) {
    // test what 'this' is bound to
    console.log(theObj);

    // call render method
    theObj.render();
});
```

**Update:** the `this` you are passing in the `forEach` call is passing the current value of `this` to the loop. At that point, `this` is executed within the scope of `window`, and that's why `this` is `window`. You do not need to pass `this` if you do not wish to refer to the window, and since `window` is global you really have no need to pass `this` at all, so I've removed it from the suggested answer.

**Update:** the MDN is a great resource for JavaScript documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: You are correct. I've accepted the other answer just because he/she did technically answer the question (in terms of `this`). The fault is mine for asking a flawed question!

Comment: It was a valid question :)